# c# - ITaskFolder and ITaskDefinition for Window Task Scheduler Registration - Password authentication without saving network credentials

Tags: c#, windows-task-scheduler

Our C# application has a feature that uses the `ITaskFolder` and `ITaskDefinition` (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itaskfolder-registertaskdefinition) COM interfaces to automatically register a task. The use case is that the user provides their username and password, and the task is registered with the `Run whether user is logged on or not` logon option. This is accoplished like so: `folder.RegisterTaskDefinition("task name", task, (int)_TASK_CREATION.TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, username, password, _TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_PASSWORD, null)`. However, the issue I'm having is that this defaults to have the `Do not store password. The task will only have access to local computer resources` *unchecked*. This is fine in many cases, but this can be disallowed by the `Network Access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication` security policy.

My question is simple: how can I set this checkbox to checked through the `ITaskFolder` interface during task registration? I've had a look at the task schema (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-schema) but I don't see an immediate way to check that box.

I set the task up the way I wanted, then used the same interfaces to inspect the XML. The only difference is the logon type: `S4U` instead of `Password`:

[image]

However, when I use `_TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_S4U` to register the task in the code, I get an access denied error. Also according to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itaskfolder-registertaskdefinition), that doesn't like a complete solution anyway. Something else must be different as well

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question, because it seems that S4U requires admin privileges. So, running the application as admin resolves it. Not the answer I was hoping for, but at least I have it worked out.